# Autofac Registration technique for this specific issue

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, autofac, domain-events

**I have this class:**

```
public class AutofacEventContainer : IEventContainer
    {
        private readonly IComponentContext _context;

        public AutofacEventContainer(IComponentContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IEnumerable<IDomainEventHandler<T>> Handlers<T>(T domainEvent)
                                               where T : IDomainEvent
        {
            return _context.Resolve<IEnumerable<IDomainEventHandler<T>>>();
        }
    }
```

**The `IEventContainer` look like this:**

```
public interface IEventContainer
    {

        IEnumerable<IDomainEventHandler<T>> Handlers<T>(T domainEvent)
            where T : IDomainEvent;
    }
```

**Now this `IEventContainer` is used in a class `DomainEvents` like this:**

```
public static class DomainEvents
    {

        ....................................
        ....................................

        public static IEventContainer Container;




        public static void Raise<T>(T domainEvent) where T : IDomainEvent
        {
            if (Container != null)
                foreach (var handler in Container.Handlers(domainEvent))
                    handler.Handle(domainEvent);

            // registered actions, typically used for unit tests.
            if (_actions != null)
                foreach (var action in _actions)
                    if (action is Action<T>)
                        ((Action<T>)action)(domainEvent);
        }


    }
```

**My aim is to have the `DomainEvents.Container` registered so that all handlers are resolved.**

```
 public class SomeModule : Module
   {
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            base.Load(builder);

            //Wrong way in Autofac
            //Because the following line is Ninject-like
            DomainEvents.Container = new AutofacContainer(componentContext);

           //What is the correct way to register it to achieve the above intent?

         }
    }
```

**What is the way to do this in Autofac?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have a memory leak if you resolve out of the root scope. (See [this post](http://nblumhardt.com/2011/01/an-autofac-lifetime-primer) for a good overview of lifetime scopes in Autofac.) A better way to do it would be like this:

```
interface IEventRaiser
{
    void Raise<TEvent>(TEvent @event) where TEvent : IDomainEvent;
}

class AutofacEventRaiser : IEventRaiser
{
    private readonly ILifetimeScope context;

    public AutofaceEventRaiser(ILifetimeScope context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void Raise<TEvent>(TEvent @event) where TEvent : IDomainEvent
    {
        using(var scope = context.BeginLifetimeScope("eventRaiser"))
        {
            foreach(var handler in scope.Resolve<IEnumerable<IDomainEventHandler<TEvent>>>())
            {
                handler.Handle(@event);
            }
        } // scope is disposed - no memory leak
    }
}


// then, in the composition root:

IContainer theContainer = BuildTheAutofacContainer();
DomainEvents.EventRaiser = new AutofacEventRaiser(theContainer);
```

This is the simple answer, but there is one more caveat you should be aware of...

The question is whether you really want to use a static `IEventRaiser`. DI purists will generally say, "no - you should inject an instance of your `IEventRaiser` into every class that needs one", but others [have argued that a static event raiser is OK.](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/06/14/domain-events-salvation/)

Be sure you are aware of how Autofac's lifetime scopes work before you make this decsion, because it could affect component sharing. For example, say `SomeClass` has an instance of `SomeDependency` and it raises `SomeEvent`. Let us also assume that `SomeDependency` is `InstancePerLifetimeScope`.

- If `SomeClass` gets the `IEventRaiser` injected, then the handlers will be invoked on the same lifetime scope, and will be injected with the same instance of `SomeDependency`.
- If `SomeClass` uses a static `IEventRaiser`, then the handlers will be invoked on a different lifetime scope, and will be injected with a different instance of `SomeDependency`.

You can see why this matters if you imagine that `SomeDependency` is something like a DB transaction.

Comment: In `void Raise<TEvent>(TEvent @event) where T : IDomainEvent;` should `T` be `TEvent`?

Comment: @Sartorial yep, fixed

Comment: `BeginLifetimeScope` is showing up as unresolved symbol...am I missing a reference ? Am using Autofac v3.0

Comment: oops - see update. `BeginLifetimeScope` is defined on `ILifetimeScope`, not `IComponentContext`.

Comment: Thanks! Is there further changes to `DomainEvents` class itself ? Should I be referencing `IEventRaiser` there?

Comment: I changed the `Raise` method in `DomainEvents` class to be like this `if (Raiser != null)
                Raiser.Raise(@event);`. And that works.